EEVEE NEXT: Hard Shadows of SunLight with ToonShader
does anybody here know how to achieve harder edges on the sunlight, falling through the window? I didn't seem to find adjustments that do the work, so I thought I'd just ask if anybody has an idea. 
this are my current preferences:

and the prefs of the sun light:


ok i found out that it was connected to the orthographic camera somehow. using a perspective camera works just fine and produces hard edges!
